# "Something went wrong: parameters are of unsupported type" when calling a function

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am working on a website for a school project and I am making a review generator. I believe hat the error is something due to an incorrect data type being passed the function but im not sure why. So far this is what i have for this part of the code:

```
truckReviewCreationSQL = """
        INSERT INTO truckReviews (reviewID, truckID, user, comment, sosRating, qatRating, vfmRating, reply)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    """

def ReviewGenerator():
        db = sqlite3.connect('D:\\Documents\\wlayton\\My Documents\\Coding\\Year 12\\FA 2\\FA2 - Food Truck Website\\truckDB.db')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        global trucksTable
        print("here")
        for truck in trucksTable:
            counter = 0
            numberReviews = random.randint(50,150)
            print("here")
            while counter < numberReviews:
                sos = random.randint(1,3) #Speed of service
                qat = random.randint(1,3) #quality and taste
                vfm = random.randint(1,3) #value for money
                comment = "" 
                logedIn = "Review-Robot"
                RatingID = db.cursor().execute("SELECT reviewID + 1 FROM truckReviews ORDER BY reviewID DESC LIMIT 1").fetchone()
                if RatingID == None:
                    RatingID = 0
                else:
                    RatingID = RatingID[0]
                cursor.execute(truckReviewCreationSQL, (RatingID, int(truck[0]), logedIn, comment, sos, qat, vfm, "",)) #adds review to db
                db.commit()
                counter = counter + 1
            print("here - tru") #<------------------------------------ The error pops up after here
            TruckRatingUpdate(truck[0]) #<-------- truck[0] is the id of a truck eg. 116
            print("here - finish tru")
```

This is the function it is calling upon:

```
ratingTableUpdate = """
        UPDATE truckRating
        SET numReviews == ?
        SET reviewAvg == ?
        WHERE truckID == ? 
    """

 def TruckRatingUpdate(truckID):
        db = sqlite3.connect('D:\\Documents\\wlayton\\My Documents\\Coding\\Year 12\\FA 2\\FA2 - Food Truck Website\\truckDB.db')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        numberReviews = db.cursor().execute("SELECT count(truckID) FROM truckReviews WHERE truckID = ?", truckID).fetchone()
        print(str(numberReviews) + " and " + str(numberReviews[0]))
        if numberReviews[0] > 0:
            sosRating = db.cursor().execute("SELECT sosRating FROM truckReviews WHERE truckID = ?", truckID).fetchall()
            qatRating = db.cursor().execute("SELECT qatRating FROM truckReviews WHERE truckID = ?", truckID).fetchall()
            vfmRating = db.cursor().execute("SELECT vfmRating FROM truckReviews WHERE truckID = ?", truckID).fetchall()
            Total = 0
            for rating in sosRating:
                Total = Total + rating[0]
            for rating in qatRating:
                Total = Total + rating[0]
            for rating in vfmRating:
                Total = Total + rating[0]
            average=Total/(numberReviews[0]*3)
            print("here")
            cursor.execute(ratingTableUpdate, (numberReviews[0], average, truckID,)) #updates review in db
            db.commit()
```

This is the function it is calling upon and upon calling it i gives the error "Something went wrong: parameters are of unsupported type" so im assuming what i am trying to pass the TruckRatingUpdate(truckID) function is not allowed or incorrect. it is supposed to calculate the average rating for the truck through its reviews then update the SQL table with the new values.
Thanks,
Will

Comment: You can't have two `SET` clauses in an `UPDATE` query. If you want to set multiple columns, separate them with comma: `SET numReviews = ?, reviewAvg = ?`. Also, SQL uses `=` for assignment and comparisons, not `==`.

Comment: Why are you doing 3 different queries instead of `SELECT sosRating, qatRating, vfmRating FROM TruckReviews WHERE TrickID = ?`

Comment: And if you just need the average, you can calculate that in SQL: `SELECT AVG(sosRationg + qatRating + vfmRating) ...`

Comment: Thankyou, ill give that a go now.

Comment: Bramar, when i pass an int into: `numberReviews = db.cursor().execute("SELECT count(truckID) FROM truckReviews WHERE truckID = ?", truckID).fetchone()` it gives and error, and if a pass a tuple with a similar think but g. `cat = (11, "house", "dog")` and put `cat[0]` it works but doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect SQL syntax in `ratingTableUpdate`. There should just be one `SET` clause, with the columns separated by `,`.

But there's no need for all these separate queries, as you can use `UPDATE-FROM` to update `TruckRating` directly from `TruckReviews`

```
def TruckRatingUpdate(truckID):
    db = sqlite3.connect('D:\\Documents\\wlayton\\My Documents\\Coding\\Year 12\\FA 2\\FA2 - Food Truck Website\\truckDB.db')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''UPDATE TruckRatings
        SET numReviews = x.num, x.ReviewAvg as av
        FROM (
            SELECT COUNT(*) as num, AVG(sosRationg + qatRating + vfmRating) AS av
            FROM TruckReviews
            WHERE TruckId = ?) AS x
        WHERE TruckID = ?''', (TruckID, TruckID))
    db.commit()
```